# Difference between pointer call and refrence call

Tags: c++

I was randomly playing with pointers and refrences.

```cpp
class Product {
    int price,qty;
    
    public:
    void setData(int price, int qty) {
        this->price = price;
        (*this).qty = qty;
    }
    void billing() {
        cout << price * qty;
    }
};

int main() {
    Product *PenObj;
    (*PenObj).setData(50,25);
    (*PenObj).billing();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this does not print out the bill. But when I use a refrence object it prints out the bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Product *PenObj;` simply declares a pointer, but it doesn't point anywhere meaningful.  You are calling `setData()` and `billing()` on an *invalid* `Product` object, which is **undefined behavior**.

You need to create the object, eg:

```cpp
int main() {
    Product *PenObj = new Product;
    (*PenObj).setData(50,25); // or: PenObj->setData(50,25);
    (*PenObj).billing(); // or: PenObj->billing();
    delete PenObj;
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
int main() {
    Product PenObj;
    Product *PenObjPtr = &PenObj;
    (*PenObjPtr).setData(50,25); // or: PenObjPtr->setData(50,25);
    (*PenObjPtr).billing(); // or: PenObjPtr->billing();
    return 0;
}
```

In which case, you may as well just drop the pointer altogether:

```cpp
int main() {
    Product PenObj;
    PenObj.setData(50,25);
    PenObj.billing();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you only declare a pointer to `PenObj`, but havn't create the object of `PenObj`. It should be `Product *PenObj = new PenObj`

Comment: Sorry to be that guy: `auto PenObj = std::make_shared<Product>();`

Comment: @Jellyboy You should be using `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In my experience every unique_ptr becomes shared_ptr with enough time.

Comment: @Jellyboy most code I've seen is not that way. But even if it were, you can change `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` **when** you actually need it. Until then, you shouldn't force overhead you don't actually need (and `shared_ptr` does have overhead that `unique_ptr` doesn't). One of the benefits of C++ is that you don't have to pay for what you don't need.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's actually not true. The zero overhead myth is very questionable. There are enormous pressure in the industry to get rid of the amount of complexity added with C++14/17/20 that even Stroustrup wrote that "Remember the Vasa" article. The extra overhead of maintaining a way more complex codebase and having to hire PhDs, gurus and experts just to touch a given code is very real.

Comment: If too many shared_ptr are needed, the ownership hierarchy is messed up and should be reconsidered.